# Facebook Login returns to same page

Tags: javascript, facebook-login

I have custom code which was working till yesterday. When user registers with login with facebook, it has expiry date and based on expiry date, he is redirected to custom url. But now facebook login returns back to login page.

```
    <?php
ob_start();
include_once("config.php");
include_once("includes/functions.php");
//destroy facebook session if user clicks reset
if(!$fbuser){
    $fbuser = null;
    $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('redirect_uri'=>$homeurl,'scope'=>$fbPermissions));
    $output = '<a href="'.$loginUrl.'"><img src="images/fb_login.png"></a>';    
}else{
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me?fields=id,first_name,last_name,email,gender,locale,picture');
    $user = new Users();
    $user_data = $user->checkUser('facebook',$user_profile['id'],$user_profile['first_name'],$user_profile['last_name'],$user_profile['email'],$user_profile['gender'],$user_profile['locale'],$user_profile['picture']['data']['url'],$user_profile['redirect']);
    if(!empty($user_data)){
        /*$output = '<h1>Facebook Profile Details </h1>';
        $output .= '<img src="'.$user_data['picture'].'">';
        $output .= '<br/>Facebook ID : ' . $user_data['oauth_uid'];
        $output .= '<br/>Name : ' . $user_data['fname'].' '.$user_data['lname'];
        $output .= '<br/>Email : ' . $user_data['email'];
        $output .= '<br/>Gender : ' . $user_data['gender'];
        $output .= '<br/>Locale : ' . $user_data['locale'];
        $output .= '<br/>You are login with : Facebook';
        $output .= '<br/>Logout from <a href="logout.php?logout">Facebook</a>'; */

            $Expoutput = $user_data['expiredurl'];
            $createdOn = $user_data['created'];
            $todayDate =  date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
            $expiredOn = $user_data['expiredon'];
            $output = $user_data['redirect'];

    }else{
        $output = '<h3 style="color:red">Some problem occurred, please try again.</h3>';
    }
}
?>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Login with Facebook</title>
<style type="text/css">
h1 {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #999999;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="inc/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Facebook Pixel Code -->
<script>
!function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s){if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;
n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window,
document,'script','https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');

fbq('init', '1748104402093981');
fbq('track', "PageView");</script>
<noscript><img height="1" width="1" style="display:none"
src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=1748104402093981&ev=PageView&noscript=1"
/></noscript>
<!-- End Facebook Pixel Code -->
</head>
<body>
<div>
<style>
.facebookVCont {clear: both;
    display: block;
    margin: 20% auto 0;
    width:300px;
    max-width: 80%;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;}
.facebookVCont a{clear: both;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;}
.facebookVCont a img{clear: both;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;}
.facebookVCont p{color: #898989;
    font-family: verdana;
    font-size: 17px;}
.facebookVCont p img{width: 13px; }
.facebookVCont h4{color: #e31e24;
    font-family: verdana;
    font-size: 23px;
    margin: 0;}


.liti {
    height: 2px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top:40px;
    margin-bottom:40px;
    overflow:hidden;
    display: block;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    clear: both !important;
}

.bttg{
margin:0 auto;
width:75%;
background-color:#26A65B;
color:white;
display:block;
padding:10px 4px;
text-align:center;
font-family:helvetica;
font-size:18px;
text-decoration:none;
border-radius:7px;

}





</style>

<!--<div class="facebookVCont">
    <a href="'.$loginUrl.'"><img src="images/fb-login.png" /></a>
    <p><img src="images/lock.png"/>&nbsp;This does not let the app post to Facebook.</p>
     <h4 style="font-size:16px;">This App is only for Paid Customers.</h4>
</div>-->

  <?php 
 // echo $output; 
if ($output == '<a href="'.$loginUrl.'"><img src="images/fb_login.png"></a>')
    {
            echo '<div class="facebookVCont"><a href="'.$loginUrl.'"><img src="images/fb-login.png" /></a><p><img src="images/lock.png"/>&nbsp;This does not let the app post to Facebook.</p><h4 style="font-size:16px;">This App is only for Paid Customers.</h4></div>';
    }

 else{

        if ($todayDate > $expiredOn){

            //echo '<h1> Expired  </h1>';
            header('Location: '.$Expoutput);

        }

        else{

            //echo '<h1> Not Expired  </h1>';
            header('Location: '.$output); 
        } 


  }


?>
</div>


<div class="liti"></div>

<p align="center" style="font-family:verdana; margin-top:20px; margin-left:20px;margin-right:20px;font-size:16px;margin-bottom:20px;color:#e31e24;font-weight:bold;">Not a Paid Customer ?</p>


<a class="bttg" href="mobincube://action/browser/http%3A%2F%2Fdemo.experttraining.in%2Fapp">Download Free App</a>


</body>
</html>
```